# Solving the Poisson equation using a random walk on $\mathbb Z ^d$

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, random-walks, linear-pde

How do I solve the Poisson equation with the help of a discrete random walk on $\mathbb Z ^d$?

Comment: Did you try Chapter 1 in [Lawler's book](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~lawler/reu.pdf)?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: That one is about the heat equation.

Comment: @ps0702: Do you mean the discrete Poisson equation, or the continuous one?

Comment: the discrete case.actually I am not being able to use the time homogenity properly

Answer (score 3):

[Random walk method for the two‐ and three‐dimensional Laplace, Poisson and Helmholtz's equations](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/nme.178) (paywall)

[Random Walk Method for Potential Problems](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20030007726.pdf) (freely accessible)

> The random walk method is developed for solving the Laplace, Poisson,
>   and Helmholtz equations in two and three dimensions. Sin the random
>   walk method is a local method, the solution at an arbitrary point can
>   be determined without having to obtain the complete field solution.
>   The method is based on the properties of diffusion processes, the Itô
>   formula, the Dynkin formula, the Feynman–Kac functional, and Monte
>   Carlo simulation.

Answer (score 2):

If $\varphi(\cdot)$ is a function defined on a finite $\Omega \subset \mathbb{Z}^d$, define
$$
f(x):=\mathbb{E}^x\left(\sum_{t=0}^{\tau-1}\varphi(X_t)\right),
$$
where $\mathbb{E}^x$ means the expectation for the random walk started from $x$, and $\tau:=\min\{t:X_t\notin \Omega\}$. Then, by conditioning on the first step, you see that $f$ satisfies the equation $-\Delta f = \varphi$ and $f\equiv 0$ outside $\Omega$.

For $\Omega=\mathbb{Z}^d$, you can outright take $\tau=\infty$ if $d\geq 3$ (the expectation will be finite under reasonable assumptions on $\varphi$). For $d=2$, the walk is recurrent and you get infinity even with a finitely supported $\varphi$. One way to regularize is to put 
$$
f(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\mathbb{E}^x\left(\sum_{t=0}^n\varphi(X_t)\right)-\mathbb{E}^0\left(\sum_{t=0}^n\varphi(X_t)\right)\right).
$$
You can use e.g. a coupling of walks started from $0$ and $x$ to see that the limit exists.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to me that your f should have a factor (1/2d).